# What characters are allowed in ClearCase activity name?

Tags: clearcase

I want to write script for internal issue tracking system, integrated with ClearCase, that checks activity name (typed by user) for illegal characters. Unfortunatly, I can't find list of characters, allowed by ClearCase. Does anybody know where to get it?

UPD: I'm looking for a link to a document, that specifies the allowed characters (or says that all characters are allowed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding **[`mkactivity`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkactivity.htm)** (the command used for creating activity), there is:

- no special limitation for the activity *headline*
- follow the same limitations than any other clearcase object ID name (see below):

  cmd-context mkactivity -headline "Create directories" create_directories
  Created activity "create_directories".
  Set activity "create_directories" in view "webo_integ".

[alt text http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/images/activity.gif](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/images/activity.gif)

The [`cleartool` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/cleartool.htm) about arguments in cleartool command is clear:

> In object-creation commands, you must compose the object name according to these rules:

- It must contain **only letters, digits, and the special characters underscore (_), period (.), and hyphen (-)**.
  A hyphen cannot be used as the first character of a name.
- It must not be an integer; this restriction includes octal and hexadecimal integer values. However, noninteger names are allowed.
- It must not be one of the special names “ . “, “ .. “, or “ ... “.

> cleartool supports object names of up to 1024 bytes in length, although Windows imposes a limit of 260 bytes on object names.